# java.io.IOException: Read did not get bytes, but bytes are available

Tags: jax-ws, axis

I have a client created using jax-ws running on weblogic 10.3 that when calls an axis 1.4 web service returns randomly the following exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Read did not get bytes, but bytes are available
 at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.TidyXMLStreamReader.close(TidyXMLStreamReader.java:69)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:551)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:127)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)
 at $Proxy302.getPodWSbyPresa(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the classes that call the service in https, use the JSSE for the management of SSL / HTTPS. 
In WebLogic go DomainName -> Environment -> Servers -> select a server -> SSL tab -> Advanced option (below) -> select Use SSL JSSE